# Unresolved dependency when `dependOn` a local project

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a scala project which is build using `sbt`. I want to import another project, which is also build using `sbt`, and which is local on my machine.

My project structure looks like this:

```
my-project/build.sbt
my-project/external-project/
my-project/external-project/build.sbt
my-project/external-project/...
my-project/src/test
my-project/src/main
my-project/...
```

my `build.sbt` looks like this:

```
lazy val root = Project("my-project", file("."))
  .dependsOn(RootProject(file("./external-project/")))
  .settings(
    ...
    )
```

and this is what `sbt "compile"` gives me

```
[warn] Binary version (2.11) for dependency org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.11.8
[warn]  in my-project#my-project_2.10;0.1-SNAPSHOT differs from Scala binary version in project (2.10).
[info] Resolving externalproject#externalproject.10;0.1 ...
[warn]  module not found: externalproject#externalproject.10;0.1
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/martin/.ivy2/local/externalproject/externalproject_2.10/0.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/externalproject/externalproject_2.10/0.1/externalproject_2.10-0.1.pom
[info] Resolving com.github.scopt#scopt_2.11;3.5.0 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: externalproject#externalproject_2.10;0.1: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      externalproject:externalproject_2.10:0.1
[warn]        +- my-project:my-project_2.10:0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

The external project is a git submodule. Neither projects uses Maven in any way.

I just want the files in `my-project` to be able to import the scala files in `external-project`, but I can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong? Do I need to restrcture my project?

Comment: Could you replace `RootProject(file("./external-project/"))` on `file("external-project")` and try again?

Comment: I tried that initially; the only difference is that `/...../my-project/build.sbt:4: warning: method fileToRef in object Reference is deprecated: Explicitly wrap the File in a call to RootProject.
  .dependsOn(file("./fpga-tidbits/"))` is written above what I posted as output.

Comment: Can you also share project definition of `external-project`?

Comment: Sure, its [here](https://github.com/maltanar/fpga-tidbits), although I don't see how that matters, as the external project builds just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't specified the `scalaVersion` for the current project, and it defaults to `2.10`. For your external project you have specified some `scalaVersion` from the `2.11` series. You can see this in the artifact's name: `externalproject_2.10`, where the `_2.10` suffix stands for the Scala version the artifact was built with. Your external project doesn't provide an artifact for Scala 2.10, hence this error. Since Scala major releases are not binary compatible, you can't combine them dependency-wise.

To fix this, specify the Scala version in your `build.sbt`: `scalaVersion := "2.11.8"`.